# How to return PBIs with no children in PBI's iteration

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I would like to create a query via the TFS 2015 Query Editor that returns all PBIs which do not have any children that are in the same iteration as the PBI itself.

I went as far as this, but I'm struggling to compare the children with the parent's iteration:

[image: TFS Query]

Obviously the variable `@ParentIteration` does not exist... Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: How are you setting the value for the parent iteration path?  Something like @currentiteration or just hardcoded?  Is there any reason you can't just duplicate that in the child query? So find me pbis in iteration 1 that don't have any child tasks in iteration 1.

Comment: I have various PBIs in a number of iterations. I do not which my query to target a specific iteration but any existing iteration (else I would be able to fix this one easily by setting the iteration)

Comment: Ah, I get it now.  There isn't any way to achieve this in a query.  You'll have to do something custom with the tfs api.  An alternative is to use a tool such as (my company's) TFSRippler or TFSAggregator to monitor changes to a PBIs iteration path which would then cascade down to any child work items to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No default way to achieve this. You need to use TFS api to implement this.

.net code snippet to find linked work items using TFS API:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("URL"));
 WorkItemStore workitemstores = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
 WorkItem workitem = workitemstores.GetWorkItem(ID);
    if(workitem.Links.Count!=0)
            {
                foreach (Link link in workitem.Links)
                {
                    RelatedLink relatedLink = link as RelatedLink;
                    if (relatedLink != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(relatedLink.RelatedWorkItemId);
                    }
                }
            }
```

REST API to get a list of work items:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version={version}[&ids={string}&fields={string}&asOf={DateTime}&$expand={enum{relations}]
```